# cannot read property 'decode' of null : react-native-pure-jwt

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, jwt

I got errors with react-native-pure-jwt

I want to decode JWTs in React Native using react-native-pure-jwt. So, I started by installing the package then :

```
import {decode} from "react-native-pure-jwt";

decode(
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJKb2UifQ.ipevRNuRP6HflG8cFKnmUPtypruRC4fb1DWtoLL62SY", // the token
  "secret", // the secret
  {
    skipValidation: true // to skip signature and exp verification
  }
)
  .then(console.log) // already an object. read below, exp key note
  .catch(console.error);
```

I got the following error : **"cannot read property 'decode' of null"**

After that I does :

```
import jwt from "react-native-pure-jwt";

jwt.decode(
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJKb2UifQ.ipevRNuRP6HflG8cFKnmUPtypruRC4fb1DWtoLL62SY", // the token
  "secret", // the secret
  {
    skipValidation: true // to skip signature and exp verification
  }
)
  .then(console.log) // already an object. read below, exp key note
  .catch(console.error);
```

I got the following error :

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'decode' of undefined, js engine: hermes**

NB : react-native link react-native-pure-jwt does not fix the problem

Need a help please.

Answer (score 0):

Hermes engine not supported decode yet. They are working o it. You can look https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/1178.

I found a solution and parsed my jwt token.

```
npm install core-js-pure

import atob from "core-js-pure/stable/atob";

parseJwt(token) {
    let base64Url = token.split('.')[1]
    let base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')
    console.log("base64",base64)
    let jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(
        atob(base64)
            .split('')
            .map(function (c) {
                return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2)
            })
            .join('')
    )
    return JSON.parse(jsonPayload)
}
```